# What is so great about Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, eclipse, xcode

In my admittedly somewhat short time as programmer, I have used many development environments on many platforms. Most notably, Eclipse/Linux, XCode/OSX, CLI/editor/Linux, VisualDSP/Blackfin/Windows and MSVC/Windows. (I used each one for several months)

There are neat features in pretty much all of them. But somehow, I just can't find any in MSVC. Then again, *so* many people really seem to like it, so I am probably missing something here. So please tell me: What is so great about Visual Studio?

Things I like:

- Refactoring tools in Eclipse
- Build error highlighting in XCode and Eclipse
- Edit-all-in-Scope in XCode
- Profiler in XCode
- Flexibility of Eclipse and CLI/editor
- Data plotting in VisualDSP

Things I don't like

- Build error display in MSVC (not highlighted in code)

Honestly, this is not meant to be a rant. Of course I am a Mac-head and biased as hell, but I *have* to use MSVC on the job, so I really *want* to like it.

Comment: It lets you create an app without bothering to write much code - drag-n-drop programming - great for newbies who can't write much code anyway.

Comment: That's not what I do, typically. Which might explain why I didn't find all those neat features.

Comment: You are surely biased as hell. Your "don't like" list is nonsense, especially the first one. It is customizable, so don't complain about that. The complete list you've there is just made out of brainstorming for extending a bad feature list. "Confusing UI" - I never ever had any problems with the UI, and it's greatly customizable. </end rant>

Comment: This is a subjective and from the title could be seen as argumentative, discussion.  There is no correct answer.  You need to re-phrase or at least make it community wiki.

Comment: You are right, it is a community wiki now and I edited the don't-like list.

Answer (score 26):

The best thing about visual studio is that it's the host application for [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) ;)

Comment: Wow, Resharper looks nice! It doesn't seem to support C or C++ though. That is what I have to use.

Comment: For C/C++ (and more) you can use Visual Assist from http://www.wholetomato.com/

Comment: Resharper bloats your visual studio. I'd avoid it.

Comment: In keeping with the theme of this answer, I would argue that Visual Studio bloats your ReSharper. Seriously though, I'm happy to lose a little system performance for the productivity and UX improvements exposed by ReSharper. Visual Studio feels like a corpse without it.

Comment: @Alex - A *little* system performance? Really? ReSharper is worse at hogging resources than FireFox with more than one tab open.

Answer (score 17):

It depends from programmer to programmer. I preferably like Visual Studio because:

(1) Development is much faster as compared to other IDEs.

(2) Intelli-Sense concept works best in Visual Studio. In some IDEs I noted that the menu opens when you pressed the . and moved ahead. And also the concept of Intelli-Sense started with Visual Studio. I am sorry for hurting if I am wrong.

(3) I use Aptana Studio for PHP development. It is a great IDE as it is built on Eclipse, but still I am able to work faster, specially while working on HTML files, using Visual Studio than in Aptana. But again, Aptana also has some very neat features.

(4) I find debugging a .NET application using Visual Studio much easier than working with other IDEs.

Comment: How is development faster than other IDEs? This is a serious question, since I really feel the opposite way, so I am probably using it wrong.

Comment: Strange, but I find working on HTML to be very slow in Visual Studio, and the "designer" is virtually useless.

Comment: @Paperflyer: There are many ways to check this, but these are my views and I am not biased. Visual Studio has its own limitations as well. But coming back to speed, I find: (1) Dropping controls from the ToolBox on the Form and setiing properties is much easier and faster. (2) Code highlighting, formatting is instant. It takes some time in other IDEs to actually change color of the reserved word and also most of them forget to capitalize some characters.

Comment: I still think Eclipse is faster in all respects... VS feels bloated, is uncustomizable, and is a memory hog.

Comment: @Beau Martinez - VS a non-customizable, slow, bloated, memory hog compared to Eclipse? Do you actually use both of them? I do, and I just can't understand how you can make that statement.

Comment: @Paperflyer:  This is may be work style, but I find the debugging experience faster in Aptana.  What facets of VS with Javascript debugging make you choose it over Aptana?

Answer (score 17):

IMHO, Visual Studio has one of the best **debuggers** in the business.  Much easier to use than the many graphical frontends to gdb out there.

Comment: I keep missing gdb, no graphical front ends necessary.

Answer (score 12):

Visual Studio is more integrated with its supported languages than anything I have ever experienced (I've been around the block--Aptana, Eclipse, Zend Studio, etc.).

Add ReSharper to the mix, and I'm in heaven.

What I like is the:

- Intellisense (code-comletion features)
- In-environment documentation

ReSharper is a plug-in which enhances these things and adds some more advanced features like large-scale refactoring, killer object discovery features, code validation against recommended standards (which you can change to fit your own needs).

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? How is it "integrated" with them? And which languages are "supported"? C++? C#?

Comment: HTML, CSS, XML and all Microsoft languages are supported.

Comment: @roosteronacid: Do you mean all .net languages? It seems like it doesn't support C++.

Comment: Yes. All .NET languages. Take a look at http://www.microsoft.com/Express/VC/

Answer (score 10):

After close to 10 years using and loving Visual Studio up to version 2008, I have been doing some Java development in Eclipse for a few months and I am quite surprised that, in my opinion, Eclipse is a much more advanced IDE. I just miss a lot of features when I go back to VS.

Perhaps the people that think VS is the best haven't used any other modern IDE lately.

Comment: What features specifically do you miss when using VS?  Continuous compilation is one for me.

Comment: Basically, what everyone says: ReSharper. Eclipse has most of that included. Specifics: continuous compilation indeed; the quick fix is more versatile than the VS smart tags; multiple consoles and several processes running inside de IDE; code navigation is a bit easier; and I'm sure there are more.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same question myself, since everyone seems to love Studio (and I personally think it's not even close to Eclipse's abilities).

After a lot of reading, I came to the (possibly wrong?) conclusion that: Visual Studio is **great** for .net languages, but Visual Studio for C/C++ is just not close to as good.

Almost everyone who speaks so highly of Visual Studio is coming from a .net background, and a lot of the wonderful things they keep talking about, I just couldn't find when working on C++.

This, btw, makes a lot of sense: the main effort of Microsoft is to push .net forward, and the tight integration with Studio makes it a very powerful IDE (the same way Eclipse is great for Java development).

Comment: This also correlates well with the number one "feature" that everyone seems to like, Resharper, which sadly has no C++ support either.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Visual Studio for C or C++ programming, you should really look into [Visual Assist X](http://www.wholetomato.com/). It adds refactoring and better syntax highlighting and a few extra things.

If you are using Subversion for version-control, you should also look into [VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/) (best) or [AnkhSvn](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) (free).

With those add-ons you might find Visual Studio more to your liking.

Answer (score 4):

'Out of the box', I can write a program without having to go through all the hooplah of installing CDT (or whatever other tools). This is a real PITA for Ubuntu and not much better on windows. (The updates never seem to work right, there are always stupid package incompatibility problems, or special install steps).

The environment 'feels' natural to windows and non-clunky, and that lack of awkwardness counts a lot toward productivity. Shortcuts are common with other windows apps, window behavior is the same, etc.

VS is also not cluttered by a crapload of windows when you open a project. I'm sure that there are ways to save the perspectives in Eclipse so you don't have to do this every time, but it is an extra step.

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio isn't a great IDE at all - I discovered that when I started C# development.

With [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) it's pretty nice, with features present in better IDEs like Eclipse andIntelliJ IDEA.

I have no idea why Microsoft doesn't just buy JetBrains and merges Resharper into Visual Studio.

Comment: "Visual Studio isn't a great IDE at all - I discovered that when I started C# development." So, what have you discovered ?

Comment: That it's missing a lot of features I took for granted in Eclipse, for example.

Comment: You should explain why it isn't great, saying it "isn't great" isn't helpful.

Comment: "That it's missing a lot of features I took for granted in Eclipse, for example.", the example being what exactly?

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio Team System Data Base Edition - all the tools you need: code editor with designer, Source Control, Team View and , what's best - Data Base deployment!

Answer (score 3):

Probably someone else already gave this answer, but:

- DEBUGGING Tools

That's it. Simple as that. Point me to one tool that can debug code as fully as VS can, and I'd marry it (yes, I'm married to VS). When you are targeting .Net, things get even better.

Answer (score 2):

Which one did you use first?

From someone who has been developing since...uhm...punching holes in cards and has seen IDEs evolve I actually like using Visual Studio, but I like other ones too. I find Visual Studio is best with Microsoft specific languages such as VB or C#, and it has many of the features comparable to the points you say you like in others.

I do find that I need time to get used to a new IDE because since I use VS a lot, I'm usually looking for the VS way to do something. So maybe it's just the case of giving it time. And if you don't like it try out the customisations to change it or turn it off.

I dare say that VS introduced some ideas that other IDEs adopted and vice versa.

My top favourite thing is the intelli-sense that never seemed too obtrusive compared to other IDEs, and for C# VS 2003 seemed to get a lot clever at predicting what I wanted to type.

It certainly is not an IDE to despise.

Comment: My first IDE probably was Linux/CLI/Vim, later Emacs, then Eclipse, then VisualDSP, then XCode and MSVC. All of this happened in the last three years, though. I started using XCode and MSVC productively about half a year ago.

Comment: That's a good range of IDEs. I'm a little jealous. The only thing I miss from the punched card days were the confetti wars.

Give it time though, and even though you can turn syntax hilite off, try it for a while. I find it's another way for the IDE to communicate back to me, and my eye seems to pick up somethings wrong before my brain has even clicked in. It certainly gives a big clue when it suddenly stops.

Answer (score 2):

VS is getting better from version to version, with 3rd party tools like resharper it is as good as the other tools. (sames goes to profiling.. the 3rd parties are pretty good).

basically - if you coding dot net - this is the tool, and if you're coding java - you have the others...
so the real question - which framework you like better, and not which IDE....

.... and if you are only using good old c++ I think which ever tool you're used to...
I used to compile c++ on borland on dos and I was happy :-)

Comment: I am pretty much stuck with C++, yes.

Comment: Then use what makes you code faster... if you're used to other IDE for years, don't migrate, it doesn't worth it.
(plus, I think ms won't invest as much on c++ anymore... unless you're playing with managed extentions)

Answer (score 2):

I use both Delphi and Visual Studio.  While I prefer Delphi ([for a lot of reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407259/if-you-were-developing-shareware-softwares-for-windows-would-you-target-the-net)), there are some things that Visual Studio does better.

- The code editor works better, making writing code smoother, and therefore faster.
- The help.  It's faster, returns more relevant results and is better integrated into IDE.

It's more of a .Net thing than Visual Studio, but I'm really liking ASP.Net, so I'd have to call that another win for VS.

And for bonus points, I'm also a big fan of [Delphi Prism](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi-prism), which is hosted in Visual Studio.

So, if you're writing code for Windows, there are a lot of things to like in the Visual Studio IDE.

Answer (score 2):

The debugger (I primarily use C++).  I make sure my projects work in Visual Studio all along, even if my team in my job isn't supporting it, because it always saves our hide in the end.  Otherwise its non-standard solution/project system is somewhat annoying.

Also, for someone accustomed to using VS, Eclipse is far too sluggish.  It's like an ice hockey fan trying to become a soccer fan.  It can happen, but it's not easy.

Answer (score 1):

I tried using VS2010 for working on a Great Plains / eConnect project, and it kept crashing on me.

I would like to like this IDE, but I can't even use it right now. VS2010 has the featureset I need to work on the above (with the newest versions).

Answer (score 1):

I like VS because it is the more responsive one (runs circles around Eclipse for instance).  I'm still using 2005 though and not looking forward to the upgrade to 2010 (we skip every other release, so not 2003 and no 2008 here).